# Why my javascript file is not found in the public folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to make my first web and I had the following route in my node.js code:

```
app.get("/contact_form", function(req, res){
    res.render("new_contact");
});
```

new_contact was including correctly my javascript file and I was doing that with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now I have changed my route to:

```
app.get("/contact_form/new", function(req, res){
    res.render("new_contact");
});
```

And it stopped working; I had to change the including with a / before scripts to make it work again:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please, could someone explain me thoroughly what it is going on? I have taken a look to several answers and websites but all explanations are very vague kind of:
1. The slash means the root.
2. Without the slash is a relative path

And so son.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the url: `https://localhost/contact_form`, then a *relative* path (`src="scripts/jquery.min.js"`) will look for the jquery using:

> https://localhost/scripts/jquery.min.js

Once you made the change, you had this url: `https://localhost/contact_form/new`.  If you continue to use the *relative* path, the browser will look for jquery using:

> https://localhost/contact_form/scripts/jquery.min.js

Which wouldn't work, because it isn't there.  It is at the *root*.

So changing to the *root* path (`src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"`) will always start from the root path (just after the domain):

> https://localhost/scripts/jquery.min.js

Comment: Two questions: 1. Should I assume that whatever is on the public folder is under localhost/ ? 2. You have said the relative path will be solved into "localhost/scripts/contact_form/jquery..." Why is not "localhost/contact_form/new/scripts/...." This last question it what it confuses me the most.

Comment: Good questions.  1. yes, if the public folder is mounted at the root.  2. because it is relative to the last `/`.  if `new` had a slash after `/new/` then it would be `localhost/contact_form/new/scripts/...` -- if you think about it like a file system that might help (you are in the `contact_from` directory, one of the files in it is `new`)

Comment: I think I understood, if so, I believe there is a typo in your main response as you wrote "localhost/scripts/contact_form/jquery" and I think it should be "localhost/contact_form/script/jquery". Thank you Davin!